# Mandatory and optional spaces

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

I need to parse strings like this:

```
"qqq www eee" -> "qqq", "www", "eee" (case A)
"qqq   www  eee" -> "qqq", "www", "eee" (case B)
```

Here's the grammar I currently have:

```
grammar Query;

SHORT_NAME : ('a'..'z')+ ;

name returns [String s]: SHORT_NAME { $s = $SHORT_NAME.text; };      

names 
    returns [List<String> v]
    @init { $v = new ArrayList<String>(); }
    : name1 = name { $v.add($name1.s); } 
      (' ' name2 = name { $v.add($name2.s); })*;
```

It works fine for `caseA`, but fails for `caseB`:

```
line 1:4 missing SHORT_NAME at ' '
line 1:5 extraneous input ' ' expecting SHORT_NAME
line 1:10 extraneous input ' ' expecting SHORT_NAME
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the literal `' '` from your `names` rule and replace it with a `SPACES` token:

```
grammar Query;

SPACES
 : (' ' | '\t')+
 ;

SHORT_NAME 
 : ('a'..'z')+ 
 ;

name returns [String s]
 : SHORT_NAME { $s = $SHORT_NAME.text; }
 ;      

names returns [List<String> v]
@init { $v = new ArrayList<String>(); }
 : a=name { $v.add($a.s); } (SPACES b=name { $v.add($b.s); })*
 ;
```

Or simply discard the spaces at the lexer-level so that you don't need to put them in your parser rules:

```
grammar Query;

SPACES
 : (' ' | '\t')+ {skip();}
 ;

SHORT_NAME 
 : ('a'..'z')+ 
 ;

name returns [String s]
 : SHORT_NAME { $s = $SHORT_NAME.text; }
 ;      

names returns [List<String> v]
@init { $v = new ArrayList<String>(); }
 : (name { $v.add($b.s); })+
 ;
```